# not getting the correct answer by using switcheroo law in these but truth tables work.

Tags: analysis

[image: Question(1)]
[image: Working(2)]
Here if i use switcheroo laws they dont work with the question and give me the wrong answer. please help

Comment: If you could add your working, then people may be able to find out, where the problem arose

Comment: added the working. Weird thing is using truth tables it works thats why it has got me so confused

Comment: Welcome to the website. Putting links to images of questions is not considered good practice. Look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a basic guide on Mathjax to be able to format your equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct for the first one. Put $A=1$. $1\to1$ is true, so its negation is false, so the answer can't be tautology.

Note that the second expression is a tautology. $p\to(q\to p)\equiv\neg p\vee(q\to p)\equiv\neg p\vee\neg q\vee p\equiv1$. Using switcheroo, can you show $(c)$ is a tautology?

Comment: yeah i got it was getting a slight bit confused with the expressions and options.in the second like you said option is c is a tautology and the question is too so it is equivalent. thanks alot